# SQLITE: referenced column's value not updated in dependent table after INSERT OR REPLACE INTO the host table

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I have two SQLite tables:

1. One has a primary id used as primary key and a secondary id which may be null (i.e. unknown yet) but if not null, it needs to be unique within the table.
2. Another table has its own primary id but also references both primary and secondary ids from the first table.

What I want: if some row in the first table initially had secondary id set to null but then updated to non-null value, the corresponding row in the second table needs to "pick up" that referenced updated value from the first table.

Here's the minimal reproducible example:

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.37.2 2022-01-06 13:25:41
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> pragma foreign_keys = on;
sqlite> create table a (
   ...> primaryId TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   ...> secondaryId TEXT DEFAULT NULL UNIQUE,
   ...> UNIQUE(primaryId, secondaryId));
sqlite> create table b (
   ...> id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   ...> parentPrimaryId REFERENCES a(primaryId) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   ...> parentSecondaryId REFERENCES a(secondaryId) ON UPDATE CASCADE);
sqlite> INSERT INTO a(primaryId) VALUES("a_primary_id");
sqlite> INSERT INTO b(id, parentPrimaryId) VALUES("b_id", "a_primary_id");
sqlite> SELECT * FROM a;
a_primary_id|
sqlite> SELECT * FROM b;
b_id|a_primary_id|
sqlite> INSERT OR REPLACE INTO a(primaryId, secondaryId) VALUES("a_primary_id", "a_secondary_id");
sqlite> SELECT * FROM a;
a_primary_id|a_secondary_id
sqlite> SELECT * FROM b;
b_id|a_primary_id|
sqlite>
```

I want the last query selecting values from `b` show `a_secondary_id` for `parentSecondaryId` column. Can I achieve such behaviour with SQLite?
I tried to use `FOREIGN KEY(parentPrimaryId, parentSecondaryId) REFERENCES a(primaryId, secondaryId)` instead of `REFERENCES` for table `b` columns but the result is still the same.

Comment: UPDATE CASCADE updates a value if there was a reference before, but since `a.secondaryId` is NULL no record is referenced in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to achieve my desired behaviour using a trigger:

```
sqlite> create trigger update_parent_secondary_id after insert on a
   ...> begin
   ...> UPDATE b SET parentSecondaryId = new.secondaryId WHERE b.parentPrimaryId = new.primaryId;
   ...> end;
```

Not sure it's the most optimal possible solution though.